# Remove super glue stain from windshield

Tags: car

I have a super glue stain on the front windshield of my car, what is the best way to remove it without scratching the windshield?

Comment: Please be aware that the windshield is not actually glass, and as such is prone for scratches. So be careful when trying out tips given

Comment: @Holroy - surely not - windscreens are made from laminated glass, which is simply two sheets of glass with vinyl inbetween them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need some acetone (or your girlfriend/wife's liquid nail polish remover). Apply liberally, and then you just have to work at it to get it off and that's the part that might be difficult if you're trying not to scratch the glass. I'd try with a fingernail I think, given that's the least likely to cause scratching. Link below gives specific instructions, follow the ones listed under tables, floors, counters etc.

http://www.supergluecorp.com/?q=removingsuperglue.html

Comment: Yes, acetone is a good suggestion, but the stain should be soaked for a while. any tips for how to make acetone stays on the stain which on a vertical surface

Comment: Sellotape (or scotch tape, depending where you live) and something else from your lady friend's cupboard - one of those round, cotton pads used for removing make up and the like. Soak the pad in acetone, sellotape it to the windscreen.

Comment: Use a sponge or similar soaked in acetone, and use duct tape to keep it in place for a few minutes

Comment: @Holroy - cotton pad's much better, a sponge will need an awful lot of acetone to be effective, it'd have to be dripping because most of the liquid in the sponge is held within the central parts rather than the outside.

Answer (score 1):

A razor blade at a low angle should work. I use the kind in the link below to change my windshield stickers (along with Goo Gone). They apply the same principle for fixing chips in a windshield (filling it in with an adhesive then scraping it off).

[image: Titan 12031 Mini Razor Scraper]